# AT+CCED=0,1 ERROR Minicom [GPRS]

Tags: at-command, gprs, sim-card

From: http://www.communica.se/multitech/gprs_at.pdf

> Values:
>   [mode]
>   0: One shot requested
>   1: Automatic shots
>   requested
>   2: Stop automatic shots
>
> [requested dump]
>   1: Main Cell:
>   • If the Cell Identity is available
>   MCC, MNC, LAC, CI, BSIC, BCCH Freq (absolute), RxLev, RxLev Full,
>   RxLev Sub, RxQual, RxQual Full, RxQual Sub,Idle TS
>   • If the Cell
>   Identity is not available MCC, MNC, LAC, BSIC, BCCH Freq (absolute),
>   RxLev, RxLev Full, RxLev Sub, RxQual, RxQual Full, RxQual Sub,Idle TS

This gives me ERROR:

```
AT+CCED=0,1 ERROR
```

What should be interpreted from the text and the error?

Comment: What happens if you try AT+CMEE=1 and then repeat AT+CCED=0,1 ? You should be able to see the error code then.

Comment: Your AT command looks consistent with the documentation.  Are you sure that you are communicating with the modem port correctly?  (i.e. did you already try ATI and unlocking the SIM with AT+CPIN)

Comment: @SList thanks for responding. I tried what you said in first comment - didn't work. Now, I wish to ask whether `CCED` is a "standard" AT command or is it specific to a particular software of a vendor? Also, can you explain the description of the command given above? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCED isn't a standard AT command from [3GPP](http://www.3gpp.org) TS 27.007 (standard GSM/UMTS/LTE AT commands).  It's also not in the proprietary AT command manuals for a couple of well-known mobile platforms.

The first and most obvious conclusion to draw, is that this AT command isn't supported for your device.

The manual you reference is from MultiTech - I am not sure if +CCED is a proprietary AT command of theirs, or if it comes from somewhere else.  But it seems that it isn't standard, anyway.

Having looked at the documentation, there is a lot more text than you have pasted above, and it's pretty complicated, as there are a lot of different possible combinations and responses.
I think you are along the right lines, the first command to try would be AT+CCED=0,1, and you would expect one single answer, containing the specified data set for the cell on which your device is currently registered.

Do you really need to use this command, or is there an alternative? Which measurements do you need to get?
With 3GPP standard AT commands you can get the following:

AT+CREG? gives CellId and LAC

+CSQ gives RSSI in dBm and RXQUAL

You can get information about neighbouring networks using AT+COPS=?  but it doesn't give signal quality measurements.

These AT commands are documented in [3GPP TS 27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm).